# Vba macro to combine some rows' data in a table

Tags: excel, vba

I need help to make a macro which combines data of some rows in an excel table. My table looks like following:

| A header | header 2 | header 3 | header 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | 2 | 1 | 3 |
| Banana | 3 | 2 | 4 |
| Mango | 4 | 3 | 5 |
| Grape | 5 | 4 | 6 |
| Lime | 6 | 5 | 7 |

I need a macro to identify the specific texts of 'Banana', 'Mango' and 'Grape' and then combine these into one row, also adding the data  in the other three columns. So combining these columns should look like this.

```
| Total   | 12 (3 + 4 + 5) | 9 (2+3+4) | 15 (4 + 5+ 6)|
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I should add that this table is made by another macro using data from another sheet. The code for this is as follows:

```
Sub CopyUnique()

Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic

    Dim s1 As Worksheet, s2 As Worksheet
    
    Set s1 = Sheets("Bericht1")
    Set s2 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    s1.Range("E:E").Copy s2.Range("a1")
    s2.Range("A:A").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo       
        
s2.Range("B3").Select
ActiveCell.Formula2R1C1 = "=SUMIF('" & s1.Name & "'!R3C5:R50000C5,'" & s2.Name & "'!RC1,'" & s1.Name & "'!R3C20:R50000C20)"

s2.Range("B3:B" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).FillDown


s2.Range("c3").Select
ActiveCell.Formula2R1C1 = "=SUMIF('" & s1.Name & "'!R3C5:R50000C5,'" & s2.Name & "'!RC1,'" & s1.Name & "'!R3C17:R50000C18)"

s2.Range("c3:c" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).FillDown


s2.Range("d3").Select
ActiveCell.Formula2R1C1 = "=SUMPRODUCT(IF('" & s1.Name & "'!R3C5:R50000C5='" & s2.Name & "'!RC1, '" & s1.Name & "'! R3C20:R50000C20*'" & s1.Name & "'!R3C28:R50000C28))"

s2.Range("d3:d" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).FillDown
   


s2.Range(Range("B3:D3"), Range("B3").End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
s2.Range("B3").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Range("A2").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = True

Dim r As Long, c As Long
    Range("A2:D" & Rows.Count).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).BorderAround ColorIndex:=1, Weight:=xlThick
    For c = 6 To 11
        r = WorksheetFunction.Max(r, Cells(Rows.Count, c).End(xlUp).Row)
    Next
    
Range("A2:D2").Resize(r).BorderAround ColorIndex:=11, Weight:=xlThick

Range("B2").Copy
Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats

Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: I have no clue what you are asking for, someone else downvoted the question, most likely for the same reason. Please describe clearly what you end result should look like and what the logic is you are using. Why the total is 12, 9, 15? What is this "Total"?

Comment: You can get your expected output using SUMIFS. You can even code it. Also you could use Pivot Tables

Comment: @Aldert 12, 9, 5 is simply the sum of the corresponding data for the rows of Banana, Mango and Grape. Sum of column name header 2 is 12, sum of header 3 is 9 and so on. I would advise you to read the post properly before downvoting it. This line - "I need a macro to identify the specific texts of 'Banana', 'Mango' and 'Grape' and then combine these into one row, also adding the data in the other three columns." should have been clear enough

Answer (score 0):

You can get that with normal functions in Excel:

[image]

My formula in Total row is:

```
=SUM(SUMIF($A$2:$A$6;{"Banana";"Mango";"Grape"};B$2:B$6))
```

Drag to right. Notice the critical part here is the string `{"Banana";"Mango";"Grape"}`, which will filter the sum you want to get. Probably you can code something in VBA to manipulate that part and choose what you want to sum up everytime you run it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works. However, do you know if there is a way to make the macro so that it simply removes those three individual columns and puts the Total column by itself. Also, I would like to give another specific text instead of the word 'Total'.

Comment: That's a different question and also you should try to code something on your own. Try to show some effort. read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: I believe that is the original question i had asked because if you see my code i had already implemented the Sum if part to make the table in the first place. Please read the title of the question - "Vba macro to COMBINE some rows' data in a table". if you took time to read my code, you would see i had already implemented the formula you suggested.